# Angular Universal Starter works locally but wouldn't start on server

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to run Angular Universal Starter on Centos server.
`build:ssr` and `serve:ssr` locally works perfectly, no errors.
Then I moved `dist` folder to server, installed latest versions of  nodejs, npm, pm2.
run `pm2 start /path/to/server.js --name universal` - Process successfully started
`pm2 status` shows that universal status is `errored`, logs say the same multiple times:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/server.ts:1:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Am I supposed to move over entire `node_modules` folder or what does this error mean?
Also how could I tell if Universal is actually working and I see prerendered page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to enter the dist directory on your Centos server and run `npm install`.

Comment: `npm install` says there is no `package.json`.   I thought `dist` is self-sufficient and does not require 200mb+ dependencies to work.

Comment: I copied `package.json` to the directory, run `npm install` and now it's working. So do I actually need all these dependencies on server to run smallest application? Wow

Comment: Yers you need all dependencies like in local mode :) If helped you can select this answer ;)